# Parsing NSData from GET request

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I made NSData from GET request.

```
NSString *nameID = [[NSString alloc]initWithString: @"1"];        
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.xxxxx.com/news/index.php?id=%@", 
                       [nameID stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSData *urlData;
NSURLResponse *response;
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *results = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
NSLog(@"%@",urlData);
```

And then how to parse that? I've got only something like:

```
2011-10-21 19:27:06.213 httptest[1674:207] <3c21444f 43545950 45206874 6d6c2050 55424c49 4320222d 2f2f5733 432f2f44 54442058 48544d4c
```

Answer (score 0):

You are logging urlData (an NSData object) instead of results (the NSString). NSData objects are displayed in the output console as hex digit pairs. If you log 'results' you will see something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE http...
```

which is probably what you were expecting.

Comment: I've tried to log results(NSString) and it was just (NULL) instead of <!DOCTYPE http... What was wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have already converted the resulting data to a `NSString`

at first you have to define what that data is: XML- or JSON-String? or Binary-encoded stuff? and then you have to write your own parser or choose one you like.

I assume that your result is xml and lets just assume that you want to use the `TBXML`-Dom-Parser. then try:

```
NSString *results = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; 
TBXML * tbxml = [TBXML tbxmlWithXmlString:result];
TBXMLElement *rootElement = tbxml.rootElement;
TBXMLElement *childELement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"myChildTag" parentElement:rootElement]
..... //depends on how your xml looks like
```

Comment: results is (null) when I'm trying to log it.

Comment: you mean `NSLog(@"%@", results)` just prints "(null)" ? do you know what the webserver is returning to your app?